# export with spring displaytag and ResponseOverrideFilter

Tags: excel, spring, jsp, export, displaytag

im trying to improve an export with displaytag and spring,

this is my table in my jsp

```
<display:table name="${wrapper}" id="row" class="aa_table" export="true" requestURI="${contextPath}/myaction">
   <display:column property="descrizione" title="Descrizione" />
   <display:column media="excel" property="contoCorrente" title="conto corrente" />
   <display:column media="excel" property="importoVersato" title="importo versato" />
   <display:setProperty name="export.xml" value="false"  />
   <display:setProperty name="export.pdf" value="false"  />
   <display:setProperty name="export.csv" value="false" />
   <display:setProperty name="export.excel" value="true" />
</display:table>
```

i've tried to improve a filter in my xml,

```
<filter>
    <description>Filtro export display tag</description>
    <display-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</display-name>
    <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But when i click in excel button in my page for export excel data, i receive this error: Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [ResponseOverrideFilter]: filter is unavailable.

thanks.

MY STACKTRACE

> [30/05/17 10.18.25:914 CEST] 0000001c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Errore servlet]-[MutIpoIntraGDPWeb]: java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:64)
>       at org.apache.tiles.autotag.core.runtime.AbstractModelBody.evaluateWithoutWriting(AbstractModelBody.java:77)
>       at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertDefinitionModel.execute(InsertDefinitionModel.java:97)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertDefinitionTag.doTag(InsertDefinitionTag.java:254)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio._jspService(_mutuiDettaglio.java:117)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
>       at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
>       at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:262)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:264)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1694)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1635)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
>       at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:140)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
>       at it.inps.testata.portaleintranetfilter.HeaderFilter.doFilter(HeaderFilter.java:78)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:965)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
>       at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
>       at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
>       at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>       at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
>       at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
>   Caused by: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio$_mutuiDettaglioHelper.invoke(_mutuiDettaglio.java:1126)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:62)
>       ... 58 more
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: JspException when evaluating the body
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:64)
>       at org.apache.tiles.autotag.core.runtime.AbstractModelBody.evaluateAsString(AbstractModelBody.java:59)
>       at org.apache.tiles.template.PutAttributeModel.execute(PutAttributeModel.java:96)
>       at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.PutAttributeTag.doTag(PutAttributeTag.java:226)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio$_mutuiDettaglioHelper.invoke0(_mutuiDettaglio.java:933)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio$_mutuiDettaglioHelper.invoke(_mutuiDettaglio.java:1106)
>       ... 59 more
>   Caused by: com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.WsSkipPageException: Tag file or fragment [_jspx_th_display_table_0] doEndTag returned SKIP_PAGE
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio$_mutuiDettaglioHelper.invoke1(_mutuiDettaglio.java:1068)
>       at com.ibm._jsp._mutuiDettaglio$_mutuiDettaglioHelper.invoke(_mutuiDettaglio.java:1110)
>       at org.apache.tiles.request.jsp.autotag.JspModelBody.evaluate(JspModelBody.java:62)
>       ... 64 more

UPDATE:
this is all my filter in my web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ResponseOverrideFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace instead of a snippet.

Comment: added. tanks so mutch